# .createElement() with HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My aim is to add HTML using `.createElement()` of [wp.element](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-element/) but it outputs as text, example:

```
wp.element.createElement(
        Meta,
        {   
            className: 'TEST',
            title: 'TEST',
            initialOpen: true,
        },  
        'Here is html: <input type="text">'
);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is `wp.element`? I assume the `createElement` there is [React's](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-element/).

Comment: If this React you can set html only with dangerouslySetInnerHTML, otherwise you get this code only like text, this feature against xss attacks

Comment: @VadimHulevich Please demonstrate how that is done, thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56374534/10761855

Answer (score 2):

You should use `wp.element.render` with the created element if you want that in the DOM correctly.

Please see the example in the documentation:

```
<div id="greeting"></div>

<script>
function Greeting( props ) {
    return wp.element.createElement( 'span', null, 
        'Hello ' + props.toWhom + '!'
    );
}

wp.element.render(
    wp.element.createElement( Greeting, { toWhom: 'World' } ),
    document.getElementById( 'greeting' )
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress use react as you see here from your links

`Element is, quite simply, an abstraction layer atop React.`

That's mean you use top level of React api

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

And react can't pass you add js code like a innerHtml because it's dangerous (any script can run from text).

For example some bad guy can use this vulnerabilitys for XSS attack.

But if you need add some HTML inside of element you can use method  `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

React.createElement('h1', { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: createMarkup() }, `Welcome to react world`)
```

https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-react/issues/53#issuecomment-164175324